# IIS Virtual Directory using Classic ASP parent paths throws 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7

I am trying to get a basic virtual directory working that redirects to the website root to run ASP scripts. The basic site runs fine.

*403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.*

Error from log files is: 403 14 0 281, or 403 14 0 187, or 403 14 0 62

I have enabled ASP Parent Paths.

IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, NETWORK SERVICE and Application pool all have read & execute at wwwroot.

Anonymous and Windows Authentication are enabled.

Path Credentials are set to Application user (pass-through authentication)

The web.config in the Virtual Directory is basic see below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="../default.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have tried versions of this /default.asp and ./default.asp.

I have tried to set the app pool to run as NETWORK SERVICE identity

The app pool has enable 32bit applications

Enabling Directory Browsing shows me the web.config

If anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve this I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm not sure paths can be included in the default document setting.  I use `<add value="default.asp" />` which would make IIS look for a file called default.asp in whatever directory was specified in the url.  Are you aware of the iis url rewrite module? https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite . Also, maybe this is a silly question but have you checked the permissions on your virtual direcctory, and is it physically inside wwwroot?

Comment: @John agree with the permissions comment but what’s being in the wwwroot go to do with anything?

Comment: @Lankymart - I only mentioned it because the OP says that the IUSR account has read and execute permissions on wwwroot, so any subfolders should inherit those permissions unless they are specifically excluded.  If the virtual directory is somewhere else then then it won't inherit anything.

Comment: @John ah, good point.

Comment: The Virtual Directory folder is under the root and has inherited permissions. I will look into the URL-rewrite, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

i worked config. 32-Bit app true , application pool identity

[image]